# Change form field value with javascript - Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to get the data that sits inside `<p id="wysiwygBody"></p>` within an Iframe...

I have a wysiwyg editor that generates an Iframe for users to type rich content into. When I type into the wysiwyg Iframe I wish to capture what has been typed into a seperate hidden form field on the parent page onmouseover.

**UPDATE:** --------------------------------------------------------------------

I've added an id to the Iframe called: wysiwygFrame and also added an id to the Iframes only P element called: wysiwygBody.

I am now accessing the Iframe as suggested with id's like so:

```
var messageContent = window.frames['wysiwygFrame'].document.getElementById('wysiwygBody').value;
```

and attempting to update the value of a form field called CurrentDraftMessage like so:

```
document.getElementById('CurrentDraftMessage').value = messageContent;
```

It doesn't work at all???

Answer (score 2):

accessing an element in a IFrame should be done like this:

```
window.frames['iFrameName'].document.getElementById('elementId').value = v;
```

Comment: thanks for so much for such a fast response... One of the issues is that the wysiwyg has no id for it's Iframe and although I tried to add one in via the wysiwyg's js files it seems to ignore any id being set. so I had to access it via    `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];` also the wysiwyg's body container also has no id and is simply stored inside of <p></p> which I had to access via `getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;` any advice?

Comment: every/any DOM element may have an id.

Comment: so? You suggest modifying the wysiwyg editors code to ensure that I can set ID's for the iframe and its message body is the best way to go ditching what I have so far? What I have kinda works, Just doesnt Update the value of the hidden field in source, but it does on screen... Is it because I have this  using tagnames rather than via ID's that I have this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: I've added id's and now accessing the Iframe the way you suggested. But it doesnt seem to work at all now?